# Como eu faço para retirar uma notificação!

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Estou usando um `alarmeManager` para gerar uma notificação, e quando clico nela ele abre uma `activity`! Mas se o usuário abrir o app sem clicar na notificação eu preciso que essa notificação seja removida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples. Basta você utilizar o `cancel` ou `cancelAll` do NotificationManager.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29)